# Confirmation box from server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, alert, server-side, serverside-javascript, confirmation

I want to show the confirmation box in asp.net from server side:

I want to call it from server side because I have to take the customer message from server side. I am using the below code

```
    string str = "Are you sure, you want to Approve this Record?";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Popup", "return confirm('" + str + "');",true);
// More code ....
```

Now it is showing the popup and irrespective of what I click, whether "ok" or "Cancel", my code is executing.

Please let me know how can I restrict code to be executed when user select "cancel" in the confirmation box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check it out:

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
string str = "Are you sure, you want to Approve this Record?";
        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Popup", "ConfirmApproval('" + str + "');", true);
```

**ASPX:**

```
function ConfirmApproval(objMsg)
    {
        if(confirm(objMsg))
        {
            alert("execute code.");
            return true;
        }    
        else
            return false;    
    }
```

Comment: I have done the same. No luck, it is still executing the code on the server side.

Comment: take one HiddenField control on aspx page.On confirm in true condition set its value = "1' and in false set value = "0". then  restrict executing code in server side from hidden field's value.

Answer (score 1):

check following example code.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" onclick="btnOK_Click" />
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblID" PopupControlID="pnlConfirmation">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlConfirmation" runat="server" Style="background-color: #D4D0C8;
    border: 2px solid black; width: 300px; height: 100px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Your confirmation message here.
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnOK1" runat="server" Text="OK" onclick="btnOK1_Click" /> <asp:Button ID="btncancel"
                    runat="server" Text="Cancel" onclick="btncancel_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

On server side.....

```
protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code here.
    //then show modal popup
    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
protected void btnOK1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //If ok some code here to execute
    ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
}
protected void btncancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //hide modal popup
    ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
}
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1499789.aspx?confirmation+popup+from+server+side