# Confirming asp c# action on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been searching for an answer to this but haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

When I load into the page there is a check run one the server side. Depending on the output of this (bool), I wish to display a "yes no" confirm box to execute another piece of server side code.

I have found ways to do this easily enough on a button click but I'm trying to avoid adding a hidden button and simulating a click.

MessageBox.Show isn't an option in this case as I get the following error:

> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running
>   in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation

Is there any way to achieve this without simulating a button click?

Cheers,
Spitfire2k6

Comment: You want to force a postback without doing a postback? doPostback is more or less "simulating a button click" - why don't you want to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114607/confirmation-box-from-server-side-in-asp-net

Comment: `MessageBox` is not in ASP.NET, that's only in Windows Forms applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I was going about this all wrong.
The check is now done on page load, depending on the result I'm showing an asp panel with 2 asp buttons as a confirm box.
Thanks for all guidance.
Cheers,
Spitfire2k6

Answer (score 0):

In web app (including the one created with ASP.NET) you can use Javascript confirmation dialog box: `window.confirm("Request to Confirm Text");`, and process User's response like in the following sample code snippet:

```
var _response = confirm("Please Confirm");
if (_response == true) {//Do Action1}
else {//Do Action1}
```

Pertinent to your case, you can use for e.g. page <`body onload`> event. Hope this may help.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for taking the time to answer. In this case I don't see your answer providing the solution as it's for the front end.

Comment: As explained by @mason "MessageBox is not in ASP.NET", so your possible option in web app is to add interactivity without page re-load either via this simple Javascript code snippet, or via AJAX (more complex solution). Best regards,